# Search Results Show domain account and Masterpage in the summary fields

Tags: 2007, search

I have a internet publishing site using MOSS 2007 / SP1 / December updates.

In the search results, I get different pages using same layout/content type within the same sub site.  In some pages the summary field show the domain account of the author of the page (creator) as well as the Layout used, in others (same layout/content type and same sub site) this summary shows normal content.

The image below shows a sample.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6002/gfsearchresults1.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6002/gfsearchresults1.jpg)

Image in full size [here](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6002/gfsearchresults1.jpg)

My question: Why is this happening? and most importantly, how to prevent it?

Comment: so whats the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a fairly acceptable workaround for this here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/750564ce-97b7-40ea-9636-7f7223749913.

Basically you can edit the XSLT to only display the HITHIGHLIGHTEDSUMMARY contents if it does not contain certain strings ("_catalogs", AD Domain name).

You may be able to take this even further by checking for these strings and then stripping everything out before ".aspx".

Comment: Its a hack (which is sometimes enough), but I would still be worried about why the search service is inlcuding these entries in the index.  They might appear elsewhere and then you'd have to apply XSL fixes everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the **ViewFormPagesLockdown** features is activated on the site collections. This feature reduced the access level for limited access. Activate it like this

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -url <url> -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell as you've blanked out some of the information, but is the problem that your master page (and possibly page layouts) is appearing in search results, in addition to actual content pages?

If so, you should check the 'Advanced Settings' of the master page gallery and ensure that 'Allow items from this document library to appear in search results' is set to 'No'. Alternatively a crawl rule in the search configuration should do the same thing.

If this isn't the issue, can you supply more information?

Comment: The problem is that the domain account of the creator and the path to the page layout appear on the search summary of some items in the results. If you go to the full size of the image you will find that the summary of the first item in the results shows the domain account and the URL of the page layout and THEN the text from that pages comes in.

Comment: In the image above, it looks like these are two separate results though no? Can you supply the full URLs of the two items so we can see what the search query returns? You can still mask out the beginning part to keep the site/client anonymous..

Comment: You can find a better screen shot at: http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/1341/searcherror.jpg . As you can see, the 1st and 3rd items in the results page are from the same subsite and the same document library. The 1st is ok, the 3rd is showing the domain account of the creator and the URL of the masterpage though.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Have you resolved it? Or can anyone  else provide a suggestion?